# Django squashmigrations: How to rollback effects of squashmigrations command?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have squashed migrations and it created a new migration files by squashing all the migrations of the app. Due to some post squashmigrations issue I want to undo the effects of squashmigrations command.

The problem is that now migrate command is not working because Django is not able to detect the presence of old migrations file that are squashed into a new migrations file.

Example:
Let's say all the four migrations from 0001 to 0004 are applied and then I squash them by running the following command.

```
$ ./manage.py squashmigrations myapp 0004
Will squash the following migrations:
 - 0001_initial
 - 0002_some_change
 - 0003_another_change
 - 0004_undo_something
Do you wish to proceed? [yN] y
Optimizing...
  Optimized from 12 operations to 7 operations.
Created new squashed migration /home/andrew/Programs/DjangoTest/test/migrations/0001_squashed_0004_undo_something.py
  You should commit this migration but leave the old ones in place;
  the new migration will be used for new installs. Once you are sure
  all instances of the codebase have applied the migrations you squashed,
  you can delete them.
```

Now if I try to run the following command to rollback to previous state:

```
python manage.py migrate myapp 0004_undo_something
```

It throws an error saying

```
CommandError: Cannot find a migration matching'myapp/migrations/0004_undo_something.py' from app 'myapp'
```

Answer (score -1):

You will have to revert back to the branch where you haven't squashed migrations, only then you can access the last migration build.

Hence, Django's prompt:

```
You should commit this migration but leave the old ones in place;
```

When you're sure that you don't require old migrations, only then delete them.

```
the new migration will be used for new installs. Once you are sure
all instances of the codebase have applied the migrations you squashed,
you can delete them
```